# How to connect to Az.module without run as account in Azure Automation. I am trying to do with system assigned identity

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-automation, azure-authentication

> Below is the code :

```
$sub = Get-AzSubscription -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if(-not($sub))
{
Connect-AzAccount -Identity
}
$storageaccountname="stgacct"
$resourcegroupname="RSG1"
$acctKey= (Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroupname -AccountName 
$storageaccountname).Value[0]
```

> it throws an error :
> Run Connect-AzAccount to login.

> ### Environments
>
> {[AzureChinaCloud, AzureChinaCloud], [AzureCloud, AzureCloud], [AzureGermanCloud,
> AzureGermanCloud], [AzureUSGovernme...
> 'this.Client.SubscriptionId' cannot be null.
> System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Cannot index into a null array.
> at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Int32 )
> at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1
> arg1)
> at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.DynamicInstruction`3.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
> at
> System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame
> frame)

Comment: Refer this might be help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43326842/azure-automation-how-to-authenticate-without-using-an-account-with-resource-ma?rq=1 ?

Comment: @Sachin Kindly mark the reply below as the answer if it helps resolve your question.

Answer (score 0):

Get-AzSubscription also requires you to be logged in. This is why you are getting the error, but your code is still running through successfully to retrieve the key. See my output below and I wrote a line to print out the storage key(which it did).[image: Automation output]

What you can try is complete omit the getting of subscription like below.

```
Connect-AzAccount -Identity
$storageaccountname="anustorage1980"
$resourcegroupname="testRG"
$acctKey= (Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroupname -AccountName $storageaccountname).Value[0]
```

Or put the Get-AzSubscription after the Connect-AzAccount -Identity